# Split around character with regex and conditions

Tags: java, regex, split

I try to split a string with the following conditions

- Keep all characters
- Split around `=` if preceding character is not `%` or `!`
- Split around `!=`

**Example**:

> test=45  ->  [test, =, 45]
>   test!=45  ->  [test, !=, 45]
>   test%=45  ->  [test%=45]

**Code**:

```
private static final Map<String[], String> tests = new HashMap<>();

static {
    tests.put(new String[]{"test", "=", "45"}, "test=45");
    tests.put(new String[]{"test", "!=", "45"}, "test!=45");
    tests.put(new String[]{"test%=45"}, "test%=45");
    tests.put(new String[]{"test", "=", "%=45"}, "test=%=45");
    tests.put(new String[]{"test%=", "=", "%=45"}, "test%==%=45");
}

@org.junit.Test
public void simpleTest() {
    String regex = "(?=!=)|(?<=!=)|(?<![!%])((?<==)|(?==))";
    for (Map.Entry<String[], String> entry : tests.entrySet()) {
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().split(regex));
    }
}
```

The "best" thing that I found is `(?=!=)|(?<=!=)|(?<![!%])((?<==)|(?==))` but I don't know why for `%=` it split after (`(?<==)` seems to be executed)
Left and right characters can be any of the ACII table.

**Result** :

> test=45  ->  [test, =, 45]
>   test!=45  ->  [test, !=, 45]
>   test%=45  ->  [**test%=, 45**] <- should be [test%=45]
>   test=%=45  ->  [test, =, **%=, 45**] <- should be [test, =, %=45]
>   test%==%=45  ->  [test%=, =, **%=, 45**] <- should be [test%=, =, %=45]

Is it possible to do it with a regex and split ?

**Note**: This is a just part of the regex and it's used to "easily" parse data, so yes I can do it with simple code instead of using a regex and split but this is not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the lookbehind into the lookarounds checking for the equal sign presence:

```
(?<=!=)|(?=!=)|((?<=(?<![!%])=)|(?=(?<![!%])=))
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fK5vL1/1)

I modified this part: `((?<=(?<![!%])=)|(?=(?<![!%])=))`.

```
( 
 (?<=(?<![!%])=) - matches a location preceded by a = sign that is not preceded with ! or %
 |
 (?=(?<![!%])=) - matches a location followed by a = sign that is not preceded with ! or %
)
```

Comment: I don't know why I have not thought about it. Works well thanks

Comment: Usually, nesting lookarounds is not a good idea, so it is really something that can easily skip our attention. Here, there is no need checking for escaped entities, thus,  it is ok to use them.

Comment: The extra parenthesis around part 3 and 4 are extraneous. Also, why exclude matching *after* `!=` in part 3 when explicitly including matching after `!=` in part 1? Remove part 1 and change part 3 to only exclude `%=`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this

```
(?=!=|(?<![!%])=)|(?<=!=|(?<![!%])=)
```

Extracting the *core* section that is repeated for the lookahead and the lookbehind section:

```
String core  = "!=|(?<![!%])=";
String regex = "(?=" + core + ")|(?<=" + core + ")";
```

<kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nE1sA9/1)</kbd>  
<kbd>[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/N3jBVb)</kbd>

**Regex Breakout** (*core only*)

```
  !=         # A literal '!='
  |          # OR
  (?<![!%])= # A literal '=' that is not preceded by '!' or '%'
```